# How do I write a query to get the first_name and last_name of customers having orders containing more than 2 items?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: These are the tables i am supposed to extract the data from]

How do I write a query to get the first_name and last_name of customers having orders containing more than 2 items?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a query writing service. Instead we help programmers with their programming problems. What is yours? What part of the task are you having problems with? Please tell us exactly how you have approached the task and where you got stuck.

Comment: sorry about that. i was just struggling to find the logic for this query. Will be more specific next time.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please paste your sample data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: It is weird by the way that you accepted Asgar's answer when it was completely wrong. Please don't just accept answers blindly, but read them and understand them first. MySQL is notorious for allowing some invalid queries without warning. If you just use someone's query without having verified it, you run the risk that the query may seem to do what you want, but doesn't actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
s.first_name, s.last_name
 FROM sales_order s 
 JOIN sales_order_item so 
 ON so.fk_sales_order=s.id_sales_order
GROUP BY so.fk_sales_order
HAVING COUNT(*)>2
```

Comment: Two problems with this query as far as I can see it: 1. It doesn't do what is required. 2. It is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it does not work?

Comment: First of all, you are joining on `so.id_sales_order_item=s.id_sales_order` which is obviously not correct ...

Comment: Oh my bad, i copied and pasted the wrong one. I’ll update my answer. Thank you

Comment: And second, your `SELECT` contains columns that are neither aggregated nor contained in the `GROUP BY`. And depending on the DB's settings, this might not be allowed. Per default in MySQL `only_full_group_by` is enabled, which won't allow such a query ...

Comment: Now the query looks fine. You may want to `SELECT DISTINCT` for the case the same person places more then one order with more than one item. And in my opinion it would look nicer to `GROUP BY s.id_sales_order`.

Comment: @derpirscher: No, the query is okay now. The name is functionally dependent on the sales order ID.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ah, you are right, didn't set the key properly in the fiddle ...